# Hotlink protection on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, hotlinking

What are some technologies that can be deployed in Windows Azure (Web Roles, VMs, or Web Sites) that can give me some hotlink protection? I'm not sure where to get started with this and if somebody could help me, that would be great!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure. This is specific to your web hosting technologies (either the web server and/or the programs it runs). I'm going to edit your question for you to help you get more at what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible : [Prevent hotlinking in Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859599/prevent-hotlinking-in-azure-blob-storage)

It is possible in Amazon S3, so you may consider it as an option.