# Prevent hotlinking in azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I'm searching for a technique to avoid hotlinking on Azure, similar to how in AWS one may use waf and cdn to check for referer headers. Is it possible to accomplish this with Azure?
I also can't utilise signed links since the user would have to reload the page continuously.

Comment: Please edit to explain what you mean by hotlinking: show code etc. Also show what you've tried, and where you're having trouble. Currently you're asking a very broad question with no specific programming question. Also, unsure why you tagged [tag:azure-web-app-service], since this really has nothing to do with Azure Web Apps.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Azure CDN Premium for it. It provides token authentication to prevent assets from being served to unauthorized clients:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth

There were also some discussion already here regarding the use of SAS Tokens. Combining short lived SAS Tokens and Content-Cache Header might work as well.

[Prevent hotlinking in Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859599/prevent-hotlinking-in-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers (they're not valid answers). Plus, the OP still hasn't shown any code or other specific details.

Comment: With all respect, but the question is quite clear for me (could be better described though). There is no requirement for code here, as this is just configuration of the resources if I understand him correctly. Hotlink protection for static assets is quite trivial - but as the other stackoverflow article already mentions, Azure blob storage doesn't provide many options to apply application logic.

Comment: If it's not a programming question, it should be closed as off-topic. As for posting link-only answers, this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) has a great discussion around the topic. Also [How to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) explains that links should have context.

Comment: Agreed, as this is not a programming question - it might be at the wrong place.